# WPF can't display image properly

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

Yesterday I create a project in my disk D partition and I found the images I put into project can't be displayed well. XAML code below is very simple:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfImageTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfImageTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image Width="300" Height="300" Source="/Resources/Images/Chen.png"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can see I write a relative path for `Image` control's Source property and when I run the application it shows nothing on the interface.But magically I copy all the files into the root of my C partition or D partition of my physical disk and rebuild the project, the application runs properly. This proplem troubles me almost all day , can anyone explain why this thing happens?
The original location of my project is `D:\Programming\C#\Practice\WpfImageTest` and I have already set all images build property to `Copy all the time` and `Content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your image file in your Solution Browser and set its Build Action to **Resource** as on image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but finally I found the problem is my directory name. When I change my directory name "C#" to "CSharp", the app runs properly and image can be shown. The "#" should never be occured in a project path name.

Comment: Please, mark answer as helpful if it solve your question